# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\sport-ak\framework

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

> **Warning:** Trying to access array offset on value of type bool
>
> **Warning:** Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\sport-ak\framework\class.category-custom-fields.php on line 133

And here's the line 133:

`return isset($key) ? $cat_meta[$key] : '';`

This is the full one:

```
public function get_category_meta($term_id, $key) {
        if (!$term_id)
            return;

        $cat_meta = get_option("category_$term_id");

        return isset($key) ? $cat_meta[$key] : '';
```

Comment: So `$cat_meta` is `false`. Have you tried to determine the cause of this?

Comment: Side note: is the `javascript` tag really necessary here? It seems not to be. Don't tag all the technologies you're using in a project, tag only those relevant to the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to retrieve the taxonomy/category object ? Be more specific if you want any help. Also you should add the whole function with the hook/filter you're using, or maybe even the whole class. Right now nobody will be able to help there is no context.

Answer (score 0):

Line 133 is checking if variable `$key` is existing, and if it is, it tries to return something from a different variable: `$cat_meta`.

You should check if variable `$cat_meta[$key]` exists, like this:

```
return isset($cat_meta[$key]) ? $cat_meta[$key] : '';
```